# Mapping a bidirectional One to many relationship with ebean

Tags: java, ebean

In this scenario a `Lobby` can has many `Indicator`s. I tried to make a bidirectional relation without good results. See the `Lobby` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lobbies")
public class Lobby {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_lobby")
    protected int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="lobby", referencedColumnName="id_lobby")
    private List<Indicator> indicators;
```

lobbies table:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| id_lobby |       name      |
+----------+-----------------+
|        1 | interna-lobby-1 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

The `Indicator` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="indicators")
public class Indicator{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_indicator")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Lobby lobby;
```

indicators tables:

```
+--------------+-------+
| id_indicator | lobby |
+--------------+-------+
|            1 |     1 |
|            2 |     1 |
|            3 |     1 |
+--------------+-------+
```

Running the application prints this error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error with [com.monkey.models.Indicator] I believe it is not enhanced but it's superClass [class java.lang.Object] is? (You are not allowed to mix enhancement in a single inheritance hierarchy)

If I remove `lobby` attribute from `Indicator` class, the application runs without problem, but I lose a reference to `Lobby` from `Indicator`. What am I missing?

Not sure if is necessary this mention, but I am using this framework based in JPA: http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/

Comment: Are you using a specific framework like Play! ?

Comment: It is ebean. I have edited the question

Comment: it is NOT JPA API, instead is EBean API. Kindly remove the "jpa" tag